# How can I do a INSERT with parameters inline at SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am generating a Sqlite from Sql Server, to do this I first run a script on sql server that returns a string with thousands of lines, like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Criterio] 
  ([cd1], [cd2], [cd3], [dc4], [dc5], [dt6], [dc7], [dt8],
    [dt9], [dt10], [dt11])
VALUES
  ('FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-B897A4DE6949',10, 20, '', NULL, NULL,'', NULL,
    julianday('2011-11-25 17:00:00'), NULL, NULL);
```

But it is too slow(I am already using transaction). I did another test using parameters, and I have a big performance improvement.

Does SQLite have any way to pass variables together in an `INSERT` statament, like sql server do.

Resuming, what I need is to generate a text script to do inserts. But using parameters. SQL Server works using this:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@city nvarchar(75)', @city = @city
```

Comment: I did a profile, 99% of time is parsing the Command. 4k lines takes 30seg. I did a test with 100k lines using parameters and took 10seg

Comment: I think you are going to need to explain in more detail what you are doing.  What does "using parameters" mean?  What does "parsing the Command" mean?

Comment: @ravenspoint, parsing Command, I think it is transform string in commands. Something like generate execution plan.
Using parameters: INSERT table (column) values (@value) instead of INSERT table (column) values ('agaga')

Comment: Resuming, what I need is to generate a text script to do inserts. But using parameters

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do that purely using SQL commands. You'd need to use functions from the C API to do [prepared statements in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s not possible. I resolved reading the data from SqlServer to a DataTable, then I create a DbCommand with parameters, filling parameters and calling ExecuteNonQuery for each line.